# Reinstall ubuntu dual boot windows xp

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, 10.10

I got a ubuntu 10.10 dual booting with windows XP. Everything was working fine, but since 10.10 is no longer supported, i want to upgrade it to 12.10 or 12.04.
In the past i have had loads of problem with upgrading/installing linux. Most of the time is fighting with the grub and the windows boot manager.

Back to the point, my question is, is it possible to just simply install 12.04 into the partition containing 10.10? If yes, is there a specific guide i have to follow?
And also, if i just install 12.04 into the partition containing 10.10, what will happen to grub? will it still register my windows xp?

I'm being very cautious here..don't wanna reinstall my windows xp because it's a pain..
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The installer offers you that option, you have to select advanced partitioning though and set mountpoints.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1906884